# Error when moving a file in SSIS,

Tags: sql-server, ssis, file-moving

***"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. 
The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, 
and the directory name must be less than 248 characters"***

That is the error whenever I try to move a file from one folder to other. 
The same file is getting loaded into a table but when I try to move, its throwing the error.

I am using a file system task to move the file from one folder to another. The file system task is throwing out that error.

Did anyone encounter the same error? How did you overcome? Please help me solve this error..

Comment: The entire folder path (including the file name) is more than 260 characters. So, for example `C:\File_1\Folder_2\Input\Data_1\Data_2\Folder_3\File_1\Folder_2\Input\Data_1\Data_2\Folder_3\File_1\Folder_2\Input\Data_1\Data_2\Folder_3\File_1\Folder_2\Input\Data_1\Data_2\Folder_3\File_1\Folder_2\Input\Data_1\Data_2\Folder_3\File_1\Folder_2\Input\Data\F.txt` is longer than 260 characters. Make sure the folder structure you store or try to move your file to is shorter than 260 characters. This is a Windows limitation and it can't be overwritten and it also applies to all files, not only SSIS files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool to address just this. Can be found at http://PathTooDeep.com

Alternately you can use expressions to rename and move the file using a File System task.